# Trackpad mouse jumping all over while typing

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit on a Dell Inspiron 17R. Things are working fairly well except for one major issue with the mouse. My palm hits the trackpad while I am typing and the mouse tends to have a mind of its own, scrolling the page and clicking all over.
e
**"Disable touchpad while typing** IS selected. If I press random keys quickly and try to move the mouse, it appears to be disabled. However, at a regular typing speed, it goes haywire. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sounds as if you need a longer time out.

Try syndaemon

```
syndaemon -i 2 -d &
```

-i 2 = sets the idle time (time out) to 2 seconds. You can increase this if needed.

-d = runs in the background (daemon)

You might be interested in :

-t = Only disable tapping and scrolling, not mouse movements.

-k = Ignore modifier keys when monitoring keyboard activity (allows Ctrl+Left Click).

See [man syndaemon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/syndaemon.1.html) for additional information.

Once you find the settings you want, add the command to autostart when you log in.

You would add it by running `gnome-session-properties` and adding in the command.

See [Ubuntu Wiki Adding Program To Session Startup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingProgramToSessionStartup) (the page is a bit dated in places, but should give you the general concept).

Comment: nice tip - the touch pad had been a pain on hp 430 using 11.10 and this solved the problem.